# GraphQL schema for vuex-orm plugin "filter object" queries

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, vuex-orm

Trying to get "object filtering" to work with apolo-server and vuex-orm-graphql.

Stack:

- Backend: nodejs, apollo-server
- Frontend: vue/vuex-orm + [vuex-orm-graphql-plugin](https://vuex-orm.github.io/plugin-graphql/guide/fetch.html#filtering). The app implements `.fetch()` according to the "filter object" as described in the docs:

```
Comment.fetch({ postId: '15', deleted: false });
```

I can't get the client to send the query because I don't know how to define the query schema for the "filter object" case.

Tried several approaches, such as:

```
input FilterObject {
  postId: String
  deleted: Boolean
}

type query {
  comments(filter: FilterObject)
}
```

The graphql query request isn't sent, erroring:

```
"Cannot query field \"nodes\" on type \"Comments\"."
```

If I modify a bit the schema I can get the query to send, however it  errors about the `filter` field type being wrong.

How does the schema need to be defined for the filter functionality to work?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I'm not sure it's the best way to achieve the goal, but I found using the 'cursor' concept solves the problem.

I defined a 'filter' input type which contains the filter-by fields.

Next, for the query output there's a new cursor type which contains the 'nodes' field. Note that the nodes field is an array of the queried type.

So it ends up being something like this:

```
input ConfigFilter {
    services: [String]!
}
type ConfigCursor {
    cursor: String!
    nodes: [Config!]
}
type Config {
    id: ID!
    service: String!
    data: Blackbox
}
```

As pointed out, I found and confirmed tested this works with vuex-orm and the associated graphql plugin.

Hopefully it helps!